# Intuition behind the condition |xy| ≤ p in pumping lemma for regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

When I take a look at the proofs for [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages), I have a feeling that I am often missing the intuition behind the condition |xy| ≤ p.

What exactly is the reason behind this condition? All the literature I have taken a look at are either silent (no proof, no discussion, only a statement) about this point, or state that we want the first repetition to occur *not too far from the start*.

But when there is an inequality involved, with very precise symbols and operators, don't we expect there to be a clear proof where we ultimately reach this condition?

What I am looking for are,

1. Mathematical proof for the condition, |xy| ≤ p.
2. Intuition behind the same condition.

To make the strings sufficiently long we have the condition string size at least p. My specific issue is why it is needed that |xy| ≤ p? And what does it break if |xy| ≤ p is not true?

*([What's the reason for the second condition of the pumping lemma(s)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9269/7200), does not exacly answer my question. The question is perhaps alright, but the answers only give some examples without much deep intuition.)*

Comment: Apparently you need to look at better proofs and/or the proofs more closely. The constant $p$ is usually derived very explicitly, and this process is intimiately tied to the "meaning" of $xy$. Maybe you are looking for "deep intuition" where there really is none...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not needed for the proof. You can prove the lemma without this condition. Adding this condition makes the statement *stronger* and so more useful.

The intuition here is that if a DFA has $p$ states and there is a list of $p+1$ of them, then the list must contain two states which are the same. The string $x$ is the part that stretches from the beginning of the input to the first occurrence of the double state, and the string $y$ stretches until the second occurrence. By considering the first repeat we can guarantee that $|xy| \leq p$, since after reading $p$ characters we have seen $p+1$ states.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more, unless |xy| is less than or equal to p, does it mean that we have 
visited more than p states but we have not repeated any of them? Where the last condition is physically impossible.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. For that to work, you need to choose the very first repeat of a state when you define $x$ and $y$.